# Is standard jar required for jsp 2

Tags: jsp, jstl, tomcat6, tomcat7

I have a Java EE web project where using jsp 2. I have standard 1.1.2.jar and jsp 2 in my web-application. In tomcat 6.0.35 it is OK no problem. But in tomcat 7 it shows some messages in catalina log

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body 
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined 
Jul 26, 2012 10:56:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body 
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined 
Jul 26, 2012 10:56:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body 
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined 
Jul 26, 2012 10:56:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body 
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined 
Jul 26, 2012 10:56:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body 
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined 
Jul 26, 2012 10:56:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body 
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined 
Jul 26, 2012 10:56:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body 
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined 
Jul 26, 2012 10:56:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body 
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined 
Jul 26, 2012 10:56:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body 
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined 
Jul 26, 2012 10:56:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body 
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined 
Jul 26, 2012 10:56:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body 
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined 
Jul 26, 2012 10:56:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body 
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined 
Jul 26, 2012 10:56:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body 
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined 
Jul 26, 2012 10:56:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body 
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined 
Jul 26, 2012 10:56:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body 
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
```

My guess is that jsp 2 has included features of standard tags. So, I might not need to include standard jar for a jsp2 application. Is this correct or if this is wrong then why this messages are appearing ?

Comment: Yes, the servlet container will supply the servlet and jsp API. They should not be included in your application.

Comment: You can download/use [JSTL 1.2](http://search.maven.org/#browse|707331597), a single .jar.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable  comments. I found that all tlds in standard-1.1.2 jar is present in jstl-1.2.jar. So, no need to use standard jar if use jstl-1.2.jar. If we use then in tomcat 7 messages will be thrown.